# How to filter pandas dataframe based on length of a list in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
id    subjects
1     [math, history]
2     [English, Dutch, Physics]
3     [Music]
```

How to filter this dataframe based on the length of the column `subjects`?

So for example, if I only want to have rows where `len(subjects) >= 2`?

I tried using

```
df[len(df["subjects"]) >= 2]
```

But this gives

```
KeyError: True
```

Also, using `loc` does not help, that gives me the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use the string accessor to work with lists:

```
df[df['subjects'].str.len() >= 2]
```

Output:

```
   id                   subjects
0   1            [math, history]
1   2  [English, Dutch, Physics]
```